# Does activating delayed durability affect executing statements?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm in the middle of a huge `REORGANIZE`. In order to speed it up I set `DELAYED_DURABILITY = FORCED`.

Will this affect the running statement? I watched IO and CPU numbers on the server and could not make out a difference. I'm also not sure if there would *be* any difference at all so I can't tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DELAYED_DURABILITY does not change the number of IO and CPU tick necessary to perform transactions in your server.  It can give a throughput boost to your workload, so you will expect to see the duration being reduced for the same transaction. Generally you expect to see an increase of Transactions/sec. This feature let transactions before being flushed to the transaction log file.

In flight transactions will use the old setting and new transactions will use the new 'DELAYED_DURABILITY' setting.  I did confirm using #sqlhelp hashtag, Denny Cherry was kind enough to answer.

Be mindful that:

> You may still have log I/O contention if there is a high degree of
>   concurrency, particularly if you fill up the log buffer faster than
>   you flush it.

From Paul Randal's [blog](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/delayed-durability-sql-server-2014/):

> Delayed durable transaction commits are asynchronous and report a
>   commit as successful before the log records for the transaction are
>   written to disk. Writing the transaction log entries to disk is
>   required for a transaction to be durable. Delayed durable transactions
>   become durable when the transaction log entries are flushed to disk.

[From Books online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/control-transaction-durability):

> Delayed durable transaction commits are asynchronous and report a
>   commit as successful before the log records for the transaction are
>   written to disk. Writing the transaction log entries to disk is
>   required for a transaction to be durable. Delayed durable transactions
>   become durable when the transaction log entries are flushed to disk.

I suggest you also be totally aware of the risk of turning on this feature especially for all transactions as you did.  You have the capability of turning this feature on per transaction.

Few resource :

1. [Control Transaction Durability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/control-transaction-durability)
2. [Paul Randal's post](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/delayed-durability-sql-server-2014/)
3. [Delayed durability performance by Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/04/io-subsystem/delayed-durability-in-sql-server-2014)

Comment: It does reduce IO because more transactions can be merged into one physical log write. REORGANIZE does many small transactions. I do not know how small they are so I don't know if throughput would increase. Do you know if the running statement will be affected?

Comment: That is true, what I meant was the number of IO for unit of work (not writing to the log). I do not know what will happen to the running transaction when you turn the feature on. I am trying to find out and will post an update.

Comment: I did confirm that running statements will use the old setting.  Edited my answer.

Comment: @boot4life "It does reduce IO because more transactions can be merged into one physical log write." <-- I wouldn't count on that all the time, it is based on the log buffers and the log buffers have their own restrictions. You can still have just as many IOs when using this, depending on how the application was written. However, it does help group commit which is where you'll see the gains, if any.